# i Can't Resize Image in XML Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview, resize-image

Why I can't display images in a large size, its results even smaller, is there something wrong with my XML code? or errors are in the java code? And i have "[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image" on my XML code in ImageView
[image: Poster]

This my code :

### Detail.xml

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPosterImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/large_movie_poster" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivPosterImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:id="@+id/scrollView1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

### Activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_box_office_detail);
        // Fetch views
        ivPosterImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPosterImage);
        ....
Picasso.with(this).load(movie.getLargePosterUrl()).
            placeholder(R.drawable.large_movie_poster).
            into(ivPosterImage);
```

Please help me ...

Comment: Please show your ImageView ... (the ivPosterImage). Scale Types should help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html. Use fit_center

Comment: where I have to put the Scale Types? @Mark

Comment: And i have "[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image" on my XML code in ImageView @Mark

Comment: this warning is nothing serious, you can add contentDescription="poster" ... scaleType is an attribute of the ImageView. Add scaleType="fit_center" and make some test with bigger size like layout_width = 200dp, layout_height = 300dp. Both on your ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its clearly looking that your downloaded image have very small height and width dimension and you have settled the dimension around wrap_content. That's why you are getting this small icon instead of full image.

And again image download libs always use image attribute setSource in their code, which also set image around wrap_content.

Now you have 2 choice to show image wider:

1. set width = match parent, 
      height = fixed(any value as per your choice like 100 dp ,200  etc), i have not fixed the width because thats goona create exception on small or large screns.
2. set image background instead of image src that is by default set by image download libs.

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.